# com.qoppa.notes.QPDFNotesView object not releasing heap even after calling "object.releaseDocument()"

Tags: android, pdf-generation

- Opening Pdf using Qoppa library, specifically while debugging I can monitor heap memory usage becomes very high at below line executed..

  `com.qoppa.notes.QPDFNotesView viewer = new QPDFNotesView(this);`
- Before going out my Activity, i am calling

  `viewer.releaseDocument();`
- Even then heap memory is not coming down.

**Note :** Tried using latest `qoppapdf.jar` downloaded from qoppa as well.

Comment: I don't see the link between qoppa and iText. What's the problem with iText?

Comment: I mean to specify that , pdf acrofields are populated using iText, just for reference . And after that i am trying to open using Qoppa.

Comment: OK, what does Qoppa say about it? It would be interesting to hear if we can do something in the iText code to prevent this (but form filling is really basic: there's nothing much that can lead to memory leaks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qPDF Toolkit does release all objects that are held by it when releaseDocument() is called.

However, Java uses "lazy memory management" when collecting unused objects, the garbage collector will normally wait until it runs out of memory before reclaiming memory that has been freed.  There is no way to force this to happen, it is completely up to the Java JVM implementation to decide when to do so.

The memory and objects used by the viewer is freed when the call is made to releaseDocument(), but it might not show on the heap until after some time, or perhaps it will be released when a new document is loaded.